# Disable inputText Primefaces depending selectOneMenu

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a form with a selectOneMenu with two option and one inputText that which must be disabled if user choose the second option. I think that I should use ajax with update of inputText and is what I did, but don't work. Here is my code, please help me. Thanks

```
<h:outputText value="Modalita"></h:outputText>
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{vociCostoBean.selected.modalita}" immediate="true">    
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Importo" itemValue="0"/>  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Quantita" itemValue="1"/>  
        <p:ajax update="uc" />  
    </p:selectOneMenu>  

    <h:outputText value="Costo Unitario"></h:outputText>
    <p:inputText id="uc" disabled="#{vociCostoBean.selected.modalita !='1'}" value="#{vociCostoBean.selected.CUnitario}" />
    <br></br>
```

and this vociCostoBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class VociCostoBean {

@EJB
private CostoBeanRemote cust;

private List<VociCosto> list;
private VociCosto selected= new VociCosto();
private boolean UcDisabled=true;


@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    setList(new ArrayList<VociCosto>());
    setList(cust.getAll());
    //selected.setModalita("0");
}

public String newCosto(){
    return "editCosto";
}

public void onRowSelect(){
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    System.out.println("|||||"+ getSelected().getNome());

    try {
        fc.getExternalContext().redirect("editCosto.jsf");
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

public VociCosto getSelected() {
    return selected;

}

public void setSelected(VociCosto selected) {
    this.selected = selected;

}

public void setCust(CostoBeanRemote cust) {
    this.cust = cust;
}

public List<VociCosto> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(List<VociCosto> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

public boolean isUcDisabled() {
    return UcDisabled;
}

public void setUcDisabled(boolean ucDisabled) {
    this.UcDisabled = ucDisabled;
}


}
```

and this is VociCosto.java

```
 package it.bway.timerep.entities;

 import java.io.Serializable;
 import javax.persistence.*;
 import java.util.Set;


 /**
  * The persistent class for the VOCI_COSTO database table.
  * 
  */
 @Entity
 @Table(name="VOCI_COSTO")
 public class VociCosto implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="ID_COSTO", unique=true, nullable=false)
private int idCosto;

@Column(name="C_UNITARIO")
private int cUnitario;

@Column(length=1)
private String modalita;

@Column(length=50)
private String nome;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to NoteSpese
@OneToMany(mappedBy="vociCosto", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<NoteSpese> noteSpeses;

public VociCosto() {
}

public int getIdCosto() {
    return this.idCosto;
}

public void setIdCosto(int idCosto) {
    this.idCosto = idCosto;
}

public int getCUnitario() {
    return this.cUnitario;
}

public void setCUnitario(int cUnitario) {
    this.cUnitario = cUnitario;
}

public String getModalita() {
    return this.modalita;
}

public void setModalita(String modalita) {
    this.modalita = modalita;
}

public String getNome() {
    return this.nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public Set<NoteSpese> getNoteSpeses() {
    return this.noteSpeses;
}

public void setNoteSpeses(Set<NoteSpese> noteSpeses) {
    this.noteSpeses = noteSpeses;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    try{
        VociCosto toCompare = (VociCosto) obj;
        if (idCosto==toCompare.getIdCosto()) return true;
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public int hashCode(){
            return idCosto;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are doing exacly the opposite of what you are expecting. You should change

```
#{vociCostoBean.selected.modalita != '1'}
```

to

```
#{vociCostoBean.selected.modalita == '1'}
```

**Working test case**

View :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:outputText value="Modalita"></h:outputText>
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{selectMenuActions.value}" immediate="true">    
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Importo" itemValue="0"/>  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Quantita" itemValue="1"/>  
                <p:ajax update="uc" />  
            </p:selectOneMenu>  

            <h:outputText value="Costo Unitario"></h:outputText>
            <p:inputText id="uc" disabled="#{selectMenuActions.value == '1'}" value="#{vociCostoBean.selected.CUnitario}" />
            <br></br> 
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Bean :

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SelectMenuActions
{
    private String m_sValue;

    public void setValue(String p_sValue)
    {
        m_sValue = p_sValue;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return m_sValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's ok. This isn't the problem. My problem is that don't work in both cases. It happens as if the choice of selectOneMenu was not stored. It seems to me that the choice remains NULL. why?

Comment: @SaverioPuccia I've tested your exact view code with a similar bean (only one String getter/setter in ViewScoped) and it is working perfectly.

Comment: @SaverioPuccia Can you post the content of VociCosto.java ?

Comment: VociCosto.java is a class generated by Jpa/Hibernate.

Comment: @SaverioPuccia Have you at least encapsulated this inside a `h:form`?

Comment: yeah. my xhtml:
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
 xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
 template="tmplt.xhtml"> 


<ui:define name="contenuti">
<h:form>

<h1>Modifica Costo selezionato</h1>
 <p:panel header="Nuovo costo">  
.........

Comment: `<h:head></h:head>` `<h:body></h:body>` too?

Comment: my variable selected.modalita is null even after user choose

Comment: This is really important! Replace head and body with h:head and h:body

Comment: don't work! attention, this .xhtml is included in another one with ui:composition and ui:define

Comment: You should try 2 things, 1 : Simple view (as I provided in the answer, but with your original getter/setter) 2 : Replace your bean temporary with the one provided in the answer. You should be able to find what is going on by elimination after that.